Purpose of Reflex in Flying Wing Aircraft
I want to design a small RC flying wing aircraft and I am struggling to understand the purpose of reflexed airfoils.
From my understanding, for longitudinal stability, the purpose of the tail on a conventional aircraft is to shift the aerodynamic center of the vehicle sufficiently rearward such that the center of gravity can easily be placed in front of it. This allows for static stability to be achieved without significant nose weight.
With a combination of wing sweep and careful CG placement, it seems that, even without a tail, the aircraft could be made statically stable without reflex. I am struggling to understand, therefore, why it is so prevalent.
I have read and watched a lot of content online about the reflex generating a small downward force that creates a moment similarly to the tail, but I am not understanding why that torque is necessary if you already have a stable aircraft.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If the CG is in front of the AC then you don't need any stabilising tail, see for example hang gliders

A tail surface just aligned with the airflow to move the aerodynamic center back just creates a very stable ballistic missile or lawn dart. To fly, you have do things with the stabilizing surface to force the wing to operate at a positive angle to the flow.
You "trim" it with the horizontal tail, generally by creating a negative lift force that forces the body/wing to an angle that achieves a static equilibrium state (sort of weathervaning) while the wing is forced to a positive angle, where it makes lift, and along you go.
You end up with an opposing force balance, the wing's pitching moment and the C of Mass pulling the nose down, and the tail opposing it. Depending on how the tail surface is angled, you achieve that force balance at some positive angle to the flow, 2, 5 , 10 degrees, whatever to make lift to fly instead of being a lawn dart, and it will seek that angle when disturbed from it.
Static stability is the seeking of an angle of attack (you could think of it as weathervaning into that angle) and trim is the creation of an opposing pitch force balance point that controls what that sought angle of attack will be.
A reflexed flying wing does the exact same thing, but with a much shorter arm to work with, that is, the job of trimming the wing to seek a certain angle of attack by creating an opposing force balance, is moved from 10 feet back at the end of a fuselage to the trailing edge of the wing itself, the reflexed part. In other words, the reflex is just the tail's stabilizing surface, set at some angle to generate a trimming force, moved to the wing's trailing edge.
The same things are happening, but with the very short moment arm to work with, you end up with having to live with certain limitations imposed, mainly sensitivity in pitch, and a very narrow CoG range, because the trimming/maneuvering forces have so little leverage. And thus flying wings are not that common, except where the limitations can be accommodated.

For stability, ask yourself how forces and moments will change with a change in angle of attack. In other words: Do not look at the force equilibrium, but at its derivative with respect to angle of attack. Or speed.
It is easy enough to bring the center of gravity close to the center of pressure - fine tuning is then done with the elevator. But the important part is that the airplane will do that fine tuning itself once the equilibrium is distorted.
The function of a tail surface is not to add some area at the rear - instead, it must be designed to change lift more than the wing, relative to their starting position, when something changes (this something being speed or angle of attack, mostly). How that is done is explained here.
Tailless designs still need something that provides this relatively larger lift change at the rear in order to be stable. This is done by adding a lightly or even negatively loaded area at the rear of the airfoil. Since the starting condition is a light load, any change in angle of attack will produce a larger change in lift relative to the equilibrium condition there than on the forward wing section.
With sweep, a second option opens up which can be used in parallel or alternatively to a reflex airfoil: Washout. By giving the outer wing a much smaller angle of attack, again the rear part of the wing is loaded less, making any change relatively stronger there than in the more loaded, inner section of the wing.
